# Navigate by page in UIWebView - like setPagingEnabled

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiwebview

Is there a way to navigate within a webview using paging - like UIScrollView's 'pagingEnabled'?

There are several suggestions out there about setting this parameter on UIWebViews internal scrollview,
but this solution does not work e.g. in the case that you set the webcontent offset using javascript.
In this case, the first tap on the screen will zoom you back to the beginning of the page....

Are there any recommended ways for doing this correctly?

**Update**
My original problem was of course that I had set paging to enabled and was setting the content offset to a number not equal to a real page boundry...

Question remains though whether there is a better way of performing this task.

Comment: For clarification, do you want a behavior like the Safari app where the user presses a button and pages between web views?

Comment: No, I want paging within the single view

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way. Set web-kit CSS to a multi-column flow.

```
-webkit-column-width
```

Use javascript 'scrollTo' to scroll to next/previous page

```
window.scrollTo(xPagePosition, 0)
```

Add a UIView with clear background color on top of the UIView to capture the user swipe gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 7, `UIWebView` has a [`paginationMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/paginationMode). Note you need to set `pagingEnabled` on the web view’s `scrollView` too.

[This functionality is not public on the newer `WKWebView`](http://www.openradar.me/18122276), but [appears to be present in private API](https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WKWebView.h).